# Cannot find package folder under src

Tags: android-studio

Iam using android studio 2.3.2..
I cannot find package under src[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hUn4.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You are currently looking at the project view. In the top spinner where it says project (above calculator) you can switch it to android where it will show the package folder "com.something.calculator" which is what you are like used to seeing. However it is important to note that in the project view that you are currently in, if you click main, then java You,  should see your package folder.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by package folder. There is also a packages view on the same spinner where you can see all your packages including the main one (the one referenced at the beginning of your java files)